# How can I produce two 180-degree intermittent rotations with a Geneva drive?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I would like to convert a continuous rotation into two 180° intermittent rotations. A standard Geneva drive layout can not do this, is there any variation of a Geneva drive that can do this?

[image]

Above is an example of a 4 slot Geneva drive capable of four 90° intermittent rotations.

Comment: Have a duplicate "cross" on the rhs? Would need a separate shaft though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simpler to add a 1:2 ratio gear ration on the output of the geneva drive to get your 180° rotation per 90° of the intermittent

Comment: Wow, that is incredibly simple.